# api calls axios in a "for of" loop not async

Tags: node.js

```
  var dataval = []; var jsonval = {};
  var query2 = ['OverallTxCount', 'OverallTxPassCount', 'OverallTxFailCount']
  console.log(query2)
  var dataVals = async () =>{
  for (const q of query2) {
    try{
    let resdata = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/gsa/${q}/${req.params.id}`)
   // console.log(dataval.data)
    jsonval.type = q
    jsonval.value = resdata.data
    dataval.push(jsonval)

    console.log(data.data)
    }catch{(error=>console.log(error))}
```

When I'm running the app I am getting the follwing output

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
[ 'OverallTxCount', 'OverallTxPassCount', 'OverallTxFailCount' ]
Promise { <pending> }
GET /SOMERANDOMPARAM 304 8.392 ms - -
[ 'OverallTxCount', 'OverallTxPassCount', 'OverallTxFailCount' ]
Promise { <pending> }
GET /favicon.ico 200 0.745 ms - 4
[ { OverallTxCount: 0 } ]
[ { OverallTxCount: 634 } ]
[ { OverallTxPassCount: 219 } ]
[ { OverallTxPassCount: 0 } ]
[ { OverallTxFailCount: 415 } ]
[ { OverallTxFailCount: 0 } ]
```

What am I missing? when running the async operation using the axios. It's behavior is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

for what I can see, and might be because of bad copy/paste, your `try/catch` is not correctly formed...

I've made a simple test to make sure all was working, and just twisted the try/catch block to be more visible in order to catch any error:

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const dataval = [];
const query2 = ['http://google.com', 'http://bing.com', 'http://yahoo.com']

const dataVals = async () => {
    try {
        for(const q of query2) {
            const resdata = await axios.get(q)
            console.log(resdata.data.length)

            dataval.push({ q, len: resdata.data.length })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

(async () => {
    await dataVals()
    console.log(dataval)
})()
```

and the output is as expected

```sh
> node .\index.js
13125
84286
380160
[
  { q: 'http://google.com', len: 13125 },
  { q: 'http://bing.com', len: 84286 },  
  { q: 'http://yahoo.com', len: 380160 } 
]
```